# PHP SOAP Could not connect to host on function execution

Tags: php, soap, https

I'm trying to achieve a PHP SOAP client to a HTTPS service and am encountering a problem I'm not able to resolve. Am I missing something ?

I'm establishing a connection to the webservice as follow :

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    ));

$opt = array(
        "login" => self::LOGIN,
        "password" => self::PASSWORD,
        "authentication" => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
        "trace" => true,
        "exceptions" => 1,
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
        'stream_context' => $context,
        "connection_timeout" => 30
    );

    try { 
        $soapClient = new SoapClient(self::WS_URL, $opt); 
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        var_dump($fault);
        exit;
    }
```

Until there, no problem seems to arise. Then I do the following :

```
var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());
```

This gives me the list of functions the service can process and I get a valid response :

array(1) { [0]=> string(54) "ListReponseAX getElig(Elig $in0)" }

The problem then arises : when I try to invoke the getElig function, no matter how I try, I get this "Could not connect to host" error.

I've tried passing the data as text, as array, as object, as soapvar but always get this annoying error.

Thx in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is resolved. For those wondering, the WSDL file had an endpoint specification in it that was irrelevant. By forcing the location upon initializing the PHP class, I was able to circumvent the problem :

```
$opt = array(
        "login" => self::LOGIN,
        "password" => self::PASSWORD,
        "authentication" => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
        "trace" => true,
        "exceptions" => 1,
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
        'stream_context' => $context,
        "connection_timeout" => 30,
        "location" => "https://the_location_to_force"
    );
```